# 'TrackableBehaviour.Status.' does not contain definition for NOT_FOUND

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I got an error when I write `'TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND'` on `NOT_FOUND` it says it does not contain a definition for  `NOT_FOUND`? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well `NOT_FOUND` does not exist.

The available values for [`TrackableBehaviour.Status`](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1TrackableBehaviour.html) are

```
enum Status 
{
  NO_POSE = 0,
  LIMITED = 1,
  DETECTED = 2,
  TRACKED = 3,
  EXTENDED_TRACKED = 4
}
```